# Remove section numbers and its dot from header in memoir

Tags: sectioning, numbering, memoir

I want to remove the section numbers from the header in `memoir`. I used the code below, it works, but it remains a troublesome dot that precedes the section name. How to remove it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname #1ignore\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\let\sectionignore\@gobbletwo
\let\latex@numberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\latex@numberline{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{KeepFromToc}
\tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[5-8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do it much more simply:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{First section}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[5-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remember `\maxsecnumdepth{chapter} ` if `\mainmatter ` gets introduced (it resets secnumdepth)